# C++ Primer 1.4.4. Can't quite understand the need of first IF statement

Tags: c++, c++11, if-statement, nested-loops

I'm new here, so please, bear with me. I'm currently trying to learn c++ via C++ Primer 5th edition, and as I was looking at SO about a doubt I had on section 1.4.4 (which I managed to find the answer), I realized I don't understand the need or purpose of the first IF statement on this code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{    
int currVal = 0, val = 0;

if (std::cin >> currVal) 
{
    int cnt = 1;  
    while (std::cin >> val) 
    { 
        if (val == currVal)   
            ++cnt;            
        else 
        { 
            std::cout << currVal << " occurs " << cnt << " times" << std::endl;
            currVal = val;    
            cnt = 1;          
        }
    }          
    std::cout << currVal <<  " occurs " << cnt << " times" << std::endl;
} 
return 0;
}
```

So I tried to change it in a way that looks more "logical" to me in order to try and understand the need for that IF, and ends up that the program seems to work exactly the same way...here's the modification:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{   
int currVal = 0, val = 0, cnt=1;    
std::cin >> currVal;         
    while (std::cin >> val) { 
        if (val == currVal) 
            ++cnt; 
        else { 
            std::cout << currVal << " occurs "
                << cnt << " times" << std::endl;
            currVal = val; 
            cnt = 1; 
        }
    }         
    std::cout << currVal << " occurs "
        << cnt << " times" << std::endl;     
return 0;
}
```

Can anybody be so kind and explain it for me? I would Appreciate it.

Comment: Try it without entering any value at all. The original program won't print anything, yours will print '0 occurs 1 times'.

Comment: [Reading input without checking for success is an anti-pattern](http://kayari.org/cxx/antipatterns.html#istream-check)

Comment: If you understand `while (cin >> val)`, then you understand `if (cin >> val)`.

Comment: Don't let that distract you too much. The point of having the `if` is simply to do some proper *error-handling* if for some reason `cin` failed to execute successfully. As you noted it can be done without the `if` - just keep it in the back of your head for the future that there is a thing called *best practice*. And one good practice is to think about everything what could possibly go wrong and taking care of it. It probably would have been clearer if there was an additional `else{cout << "error while trying to read input"}`.

Comment: You left out the comment they put in the code in the book, which explains it. Right above the first `if` statement, they put: `//read first number and ensure that we have data to process.`

Answer (score 5):

In case of an empty input or non numerical input, your second version will print

```
std::cout << currVal << " occurs "
    << cnt << " times" << std::endl;
```

With `currVal` having a value of `0` and a `count` of `1`, which is wrong.

See: [operator>>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)

Comment: No, it's initialized to zero.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thanks for the precision. Was it different in C++03 ?

Comment: Yes, I think in C++03 the failed input operation would sometimes leave `currVal` unchanged, but that would still mean it was zero because the first line in `main` sets it to zero. http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#696 removed the "If an error occurs, val is unchanged" part.

Comment: Also, not only empty input, but anything that can't be read as an integer, e.g. the string `"seven"` or other strings starting with a non-digit character.

Answer (score 3):

`std::cin >> currVal` is an expression that returns an `istream` reference.

The `istream` has an *implicit conversion to bool* provided by an overloaded operator. This evaluates to `false` if there are no more data to be read.

The `if` is exploiting that. If you omit this then your program will not run correctly since `currVal` will be set to zero.

Comment: Indeed. That's a better way of saying it ;-)

Comment: "indeterminate" has a formal meaning, and it would be undefined behaviour to print an indeterminate value. The modified code isn't undefined, just gives the wrong output :)

Comment: Yes, I was being a naughty cat.

Comment: @Bathsheba *"The istream has an implicit conversion to bool provided by an overloaded operator".* Could you elaborate on this, pls? Feels like I'm losing great info here. Bear in mind I'm a noob on programming in general.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that if the input *cannot* be inserted into that variable, the program gracefully terminates, rather than crashing.

For example, if you run your program and give it the initial input of 'a' what happens?  What happens if you do the same thing to the unmodified version?

Comment: What makes you think it would crash?

Comment: It has been a while since I worked with C++.  The character input would be valid, yes.  So it might not actually be possible to crash the program, but that appears to be the intent of that statement.

Comment: The intent is to not print `"The value 0 occurs 1 times"` when there is no valid input, because that would be a lie. i.e. the intent is to make the program give correct output, not to stop it crashing.

Comment: Ah, you are correct.  Still, the idea that variable assignment can fail, thus evaluates to false, is a concept in C++.